# How can I use Ubuntu Bold font?

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts, gnome-shell

I use dash to panel extension and I would like to change its default font. So I modified gnome-shell.css in /usr/share/themes/theme_name/ . I wrote a new line (font-family) into /Top Bar/ section.

```
/* Top Bar */
#panel {
  font-family: Ubuntu Bold;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  height: 1.86em;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum"; }

(...)
```

I want to use Ubuntu BOLD (!) font. It seems that gnome change the font, but it's just Ubuntu Regular (it's thin), and I have no idea how can I use Ubuntu Bold.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Ubuntu Bold" font family. This is untested, but I would try:

```
font-family: Ubuntu;
font-weight: bold;
```

*Edit:*

I made [this test page](https://people.ubuntu.com/%7Egunnarhj/ubuntu-font-test.html). Check out the source of that page.

So stating *font-weight* somehow ought to be what's needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change Ubuntu to Ubuntu Bold

Comment: @Belushi: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Okay, I tried this method. When I add "font-style: bold;" nothing changes, but when I put "font-style: italic;", it seems that gnome correctly display Ubuntu Italic font. I can't understand why it works when I use italic, and why not when I use bold.......

When I use "font-weight (italic or bold)" it change nothing.

Comment: @Belushi: "font-style: bold" is wrong, since "bold" is a weight. If "font-weight: bold" does not make a difference, there may be something in the source code which enforces the regular font.